# Using Firebase Realtime Database from Node

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Anytime I run Firebase Realtime Database code from Node, using the Admin SDK, the process hangs. For example, I might have a node application `deactivate.js`:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
// initialize app code...

admin.database().ref(`users/${userId}/active`).set(false)
```

I run with `node deactivate.js`. The user will be set to inactive, so that's good. But then the node process will just hang. I have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to get back to a prompt.

Am I supposed to close connections or do something else in a Node application using Firebase? With Firebase Functions, I do have to return the promise generated from the above call. So, does Firebase Functions automatically handle closing whatever it is I now need to manually handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you deal with Cloud Functions is not at all the way you deal with standalone node processes.  When using the Admin SDK to access Realtime Database in a standalone node process that must finish, do something like this instead to make sure the process exits when all work is complete:

```
admin.database().ref(`users/${userId}/active`).set(false)
.then(() => {
    process.exit(0)
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
})
```

Comment: `process.exit` seems rather harsh and not suitable for all use cases. Any plans for a softer option for disposing firebase resources when required?